# Ubuntu 14.04 not using ATI Radeon HD 3450, instead using Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics, radeon

I recently installed a ATI Radeon HD3450 on my desktop. When I ran

`LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo`

part of my output is as following

```
name of display: :0.0
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
libGL: pci id for fd 4: 1002:515e, driver radeon
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/radeon_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeon_dri.so
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeon
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast(): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/mecha/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/mecha/.drirc: No such file or directory.
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
```

Notice the line where it says it `failed to load driver:radeon` even though I have **xserver-xorg-video-radeon & xserver-xorg-video-ati** installed. Also what is this error `libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/mecha/.drirc: No such file or directory` ? One thing I should mention is that my monitor is hooked up via VGA port of the motherboard and not to Radeon HD 3450, but the Grahic card is hooked up to motherboard and is active as I checked it using `lspci -nn | grep VGA`. Also few other lines of interests(which confirms that ubuntu is not using Radeon HD 3400) are as follows

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this issue? I searched for answers but nothing I found on internet fixed my issue. I even installed fglrx drivers which didn't work, reinstalled Ubuntu and now using opensource drivers again but no dice.

I would really appreciate any help in this matter.
Thank you.

**Edit: Solved by enabling the graphics card in the BIOS**

Comment: did you reboot after installing the ati ddriver ? Are you running in a Virtual machine "OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc." I do not think  you can use the ati driver in a virtual machine

Comment: Yes I did reboot the machine and no I am not running a virtual machine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by enabling the graphics card in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because of similar symptoms, and was [reminded](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1074779/comments/36) that I had `nomodeset` and similar parameters in my kernel boot settings.